# Can I remove files in /var/log/journal and /var/cache/abrt-di/usr?

Tags: fedora, disk-cleanup

I use Fedora and these directories contains a large amount of files, I wonder whether I can delete them? The system is running low on space.

Answer (score 450, accepted):

#### journal logs

Yes you can delete everything inside of `/var/log/journal/*` but do not delete the directory itself. You can also query `journalctl` to find out how much disk space it's consuming:

```
$ journalctl --disk-usage
Journals take up 3.8G on disk.
```

You can control the size of this directory using this parameter in your `/etc/systemd/journald.conf`:

```
SystemMaxUse=50M
```

You can force a log rotation:

```
$ sudo systemctl kill --kill-who=main --signal=SIGUSR2 systemd-journald.service
```

**NOTE:** You might need to restart the logging service to force a log rotation, if the above signaling method does not do it. You can restart the service like so:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart systemd-journald.service
```

#### abrt logs

These files too under `/var/cache/abrt-di/*` can be deleted as well. The size of the log files here is controlled under:

```
$ grep -i size /etc/abrt/abrt.conf 
# Max size for crash storage [MiB] or 0 for unlimited
MaxCrashReportsSize = 1000
```

You can control the max size of `/var/cache/abrt-di` by changing the following in file, `/etc/abrt/plugins/CCpp.conf`:

```
DebugInfoCacheMB = 2000
```

**NOTE:** If not defined `DebugInfoCacheMB` defaults to 4000 (4GB).

#### References

- [Is it safe to delete /var/log/journal log files?](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=158510)
- [Surprising behaviour when out of disk space](https://github.com/abrt/abrt/issues/107)
- [19.4. Generating Backtraces](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/15/html/Deployment_Guide/generating-backtrace.html)

Comment: Same here, `systemctl restart systemd-journald.service` forced the rotate and not signaling the process

Comment: @michaelbn - the signalling has/had worked for me in the past. I haven't had to do this that often though, so I've incorporated the restart method into the answer as well in case other readers have that same issue as you.

Comment: To clean logs after a period of time rather than when they reach a certain size, you can set the parameter `MaxRetentionSec` instead of `SystemMaxUse`. See `man journald.conf` for more details.

Comment: The about said journalctl solution even works in ubuntu 18

Comment: On my system (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS), `SystemMaxUse=1024MB` appears in `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` and is un-commented, but `journalctl --disk-usage` reports `Archived and active journals take up 4.0G on disk.` Am I missing something?

Comment: @BenJohnson might be this bug - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1790205

Comment: Will `50M ` be enough for journal?

Comment: I couldn't get it to trigger a rotate using either method, but the vacuum proposed in another answer worked.  I'll see if it continues to get bigger than the `SystemMaxUse` I set.  (Previously it was unset, and there were 3.9GB of logs—essentially in line with the default cap.)

Answer (score 279):

Yes, the files from `/var/log/journal` directory can be removed.

The nicest method I've found is:

```bsh
sudo journalctl --vacuum-size=500M
```

which deletes old log-files from `/var/log/journal` until total size of the directory becomes under specified threshold (500 megabytes in this example).

Comment: safe, fast, smooth and clean, thanks! also, as mentioned in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/130802/142247 there is a permanent solution for this in /etc/systemd/journald.conf -> SystemMaxUse=500M

Comment: Make it permanent with: `echo SystemMaxUse=500M | sudo tee -a /etc/systemd/journald.conf`

Comment: I had to use `sudo` otherwise it clears 0 bytes
`sudo journalctl --vacuum-size=500M`

Comment: What is the use of keeping it so large by default? Do we lose anything by trimming to 500MB? Will we lose the ability to recover data in the event of crash if we keep it low?

Answer (score 76):

You can also clean based on time:
`journalctl --vacuum-time=10d`

```
# du -sh /var/log/journal
113M    /var/log/journal
# journalctl --vacuum-time=10d
Deleted archived journal /var/log/journal/f77f9567bb70f8e7b5d9a0c95bef5c2a/system@36170b4530af4c89ac4d84ac68f8b727-0000000000000001-00057b09da23eb2c.journal (8.0M).
Deleted archived journal /var/log/journal/f77f9567bb70f8e7b5d9a0c95bef5c2a/user-1000@54176301a0c74c4698c3b6a549e1b2ed-0000000000000874-00057b0c1a491094.journal (8.0M).
. . .
Deleted archived journal /var/log/journal/f77f9567bb70f8e7b5d9a0c95bef5c2a/user-1000@e6ecd2f858d1498b9a445af7bac00bbf-000000000000063a-0005848ac99802b3.journal (8.0M).
Vacuuming done, freed 88.0M of archived journals from /var/log/journal/f77f9567bb70f8e7b5d9a0c95bef5c2a.
root@monroe:/var/log# du -sh /var/log/journal     
25M     /var/log/journal
```

Comment: that command worked. ncdu revealed that journal logs were taking lots of space. i just cleared about 3.8GB of space on my ssd. really needed some free space.