# mysqld dead but pid file exists

Tags: centos, php, mysql

Webserver was running fine for weeks then suddenly:

1. I can access, but I am unable to log into Webmin
2. I can access Magento, a php-based storefront application, but I am no longer able to log in and it is throwing an exception error on the front end.
3. Proftpd service was stopped, but I was able to restart
4. Mysqld service was stopped and I have NOT been able to restart.

When attempting to restart mysqlp I receive the following error: "mysqld dead but pid file exists".

Any ideas on how I may resolve this matter? Please let me know if there is a specific log file you would need to see.

Comment: `/var/log/mysqld.log` would probably have the cause listed. You can resolve the PID file issue but it's probably a good idea to fix the actual problem before trying to do anything with MySQL (including starting it back up in some cases).

Comment: Are you by any chance running out of space? What is the output of `df -h` command?

Comment: It seems the partition is full. "Can't start server: can't create PID file: No space left on device"

Comment: @RyanPrentiss, I guess you should free up some space and then restart the service.

Comment: For starters I would remove these logs if they're present to free up space: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/130786/can-i-remove-files-in-var-log-jounal-and-var-cache-abrt-di-usr/130802#130802