# Partition is out of space

Tags: files, partition, disk-usage

When I was trying to resolve the issue as seen in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132265/mysqld-dead-but-pid-file-exists) question, I figured out that a specific partition is out of space.

I have a specified folder which I allow all ftp uploading of multimedia files from all users -- located at "/srv/media" and owned by apache.

I did not notice the storage allocation until I began receiving errors; so how do I ensure files are being saved to the larger partition? Must the media folder be located under home??

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
                       50G   47G     0 100% /
tmpfs                 7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             485M   54M  406M  12% /boot
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home
                      860G  200M  816G   1% /home
```

Any guidance in this matter is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe this is related to your other question. I have edited to include the link to your other question as well. Please feel free to remove if you think it is not needed.

Comment: @RyanPrentiss Do you have any free space left in the volume group (`vgdisplay`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will put the directory on the home partition.

```
#do this as root
mv /srv/media /home; ln -s /home/media /srv
```

You may want to consider looking at disk quotas at well.